list all gutenberg blocks properties with icon name as well
function custom_blocks_api_get_blocks()
{
    $blocks = WP_Block_Type_Registry::get_instance()->get_all_registered();

    $block_data = array_map(function ($block) {
        return [
            'name'        => $block->name,
            'title'       => $block->title,
            'icon'        => $block->icon,
            // 'attributes'  => $block->attributes,
            // 'supports'    => $block->supports,
            'category'    => $block->category,
            // 'description' => $block->description,
            // 'keywords'    => $block->keywords,
            'styles'      => $block->styles,
        ];
    }, $blocks);

    return $block_data;
}

Always return icon name null
"core/legacy-widget": {
"name": "core/legacy-widget",
"title": "Legacy Widget",
"icon": null,
"category": "widgets",
"styles": []
},
"core/widget-group": {
"name": "core/widget-group",
"title": "",
"icon": null,
"category": "widgets",
"styles": []
},
"core/archives": {
"name": "core/archives",
"title": "Archives",
"icon": null,
"category": "widgets",
"styles": []
},
"core/avatar": {
"name": "core/avatar",
"title": "Avatar",
"icon": null,
"category": "theme",
"styles": []
},
"core/block": {
"name": "core/block",
"title": "Pattern",
"icon": null,
"category": "reusable",
"styles": []
},


Trying to create api for this and any pointers here are welcome.
Thanks

The icons for core blocks are registered in JavaScript. You could look in wp-includes/js/dist/block-library(.min).js or in the WordPress/gutenberg GitHub repository that the block-library(.min).js file is built from.
